# Xamarin on Visual Studio 2015-Cannot find adb.exe in specified SDK path

Tags: android, xamarin

Cannot find adb.exe in specified SDK path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\platform-tools\adb.exe

I know it's there because I can see adb.exe in the folder, anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

1. Run "SDK Manager" as administrator:

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe`
2. Download the missing libraries.

   `Android SDK Tools`

   `Android SDK Platform-tools`
3. Set the path of the SDK in Visual Studio:

   `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings`

Android SDK Location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`

Comment: when i Run "SDK Manager" as administrator, only open and close quicly the prompt. I did try open this by cmd porompt but it not works too. Anywere idea?

Answer (score 3):

Please be aware with the current standalone SDK the SDK platform tools (needed for VS) should be downloaded first via the SDK manager in the SDK folder

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Tools >> Options >> Xamarin >> Android Settings.
Then make sure all your Locations for SDK, NDK and JDK are correct and pointing to the correct path. 
Make sure you are running your project editor(xamarin studio/visual studio) in Admin too.

Comment: NDK and JDK are, but it says no SDK found for SDK and when I try and point it towards it, that's when I get no adb.exe found.

Comment: Set the SDK folder to just ...\android-sdk\

Answer (score 1):

When you set the SDK path, it is going to take the current folder and look for adb at `PATH\platform-tools\adb.exe`.

It would appear that you've set that path as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`, so that's why you see it can't find it, because there is no platform tools folder inside the platform tools folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just use sdk manager and install what comes up to be missing or not found ......trust me it works.

Answer (score -2):

you have to paste this adress when you are looking for sdk in option>xamarin>android settings
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk